# Redis - best way to cache nested data structure with dates

Tags: caching, redis, azure-redis-cache

I need to find the most efficient way to cache the result from an endpoint that returns pricing for hotel rooms.
The endpoint only returns data for one roomTypeId at a time, and the data returned is a list of
`{ date : string, roomTypeId: string, price: { price: number, currency: string }[] }`

I need to access it from the cache like this: getPrice(roomTypeIds, fromDate, toDate).

I’m new to Redis, but I’ve read up on sorted sets, which seems like a good fit since it will make it easy to return dates within a range. But since I have to return the pricing for multiple room type ids, I’m guessing I would need to have a set per room type id, which makes it a bit more complex.

Does anybody have any good sugestions on how to store a data structure like this? (I’m using TypeScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted set can do it for you!

Add elements into the cashe with:

```
ZADD roomTypeId date "{your json}"
```

Now you are ready to get your filtered results:

```
ZRANGE roomTypeId fromDate toDate BYSCORE
```

Note: `fromDate`, `toDate` and `date` should be lexicographically sortable! Using just timestamp for that purpose will do.

It might be inciteful to look also at documentation:
[ZADD Command](https://redis.io/commands/zadd/)
[ZRANGE Command](https://redis.io/commands/zrange/)

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking into using this solution. So I guess the best way to get ricing for multiple room types would be to use the pipeline?  Like this:

const pipeline = client.pipeline();

    roomTypeIds.forEach((set) => {
      pipeline.zrangebyscore(set, minDate, maxDate, 'WITHSCORES');
    });

    const results = await pipeline.exec();

Comment: That's correct! pipelining will reduce number of calls